# Python unittest list comparison repr problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, repr

Im writing some tests for more my python application for a company and now got stuck with the following problem:

I need to compare two list of lists and I always get a an error when converting the second automatically generated list: TypeError: **repr** returned non-string (type dict). Which means the list I'm trying to compare with `self.assertListEqual(l1, l2)` contains a sub list again, I already checked the structure and I'm always getting the same result: there is no sub list in the list, I have printed everything, evaluated the content multiply times and still getting the same error, now I'm a bit stuck and don't know if how to proceed further. This is the code I used to generate the list which is correct and should be structural the same as the list the function generates:

```
        expected.append([])
        expected[0].append(openers[0])
        expected[0].extend(locks[0:5])

        expected.append([])
        expected[1].append(openers[1])
        expected[1].extend(locks[6:10])

        expected.append([other])
```

And this hard coded list is than compared to a dynamically created list which should be exactly the same

Thanks for any help, if more cod is required I will append it here

Comment: It's impossible to tell exactly where the error is without a proper [mcve]. But the error message "TypeError: repr returned non-string (type dict)" gives a clear indication that some class used here has a faulty `__repr__` implementation which returns a `dict` instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks yes, that solved this problem, now I get another error but I will see if I can fix that by myself. Thanks for the assistance